# Receive alert when group membership or permissions change

Tags: 2010, permissions, alert

My client is wondering how we might notify someone (or several someones) when group membership or permissions change.

We would greatly prefer a no-code solution.

We have Nintex Workflow available as well as DocAve 6 SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SP2010 the only solution is to have a job/workflow run at some interval and check against some stored value.

In SP2013 code can react to the [SPSecurityEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurityeventreceiver_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) events