# Email Notifications

Tags: email, notifications

I want to receive a email notification whenever a user with manage permissions changes the access of a user or adds a new user on SharePoint site/list/libraries, etc.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97889/receive-alert-when-group-membership-or-permissions-change